# Printing multiple pictures

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, print-design, resize, ms-paint

Maybe this question is too basic to ask here, but I googled it, and did not get my answer.

I have 15 images, each of different dimensions. All are portrait images (height>width).

I want to make their width 4.5 cm, preserve aspect ratio and print them in least number of A4 pages.

**Questions**

1. Is there some software using which I can resize the images and print them at the same time? If yes, what and how?
2. *[See only if 1<sup>st</sup> answer is no]* I can use MS Paint to resize them to 4.5 cm. What software will I use to print them in least number of pages? And how?

Comment: Your question is ambigious. If i go through path 2. You require a mathemathical prooflike costruct while on pathway 1. You dont manual assembly is enough. Anyway yes you can do this in any software that does page description. In other words Vector drawing programs and page layout programs.

Comment: @joojaa Okay, then I will assemble manually, but, please inform if someday you get such a software that does this atuomatically.

Comment: Its not terribly hard to script. But proof for optimalness is a bit hard to come by as it is possibly a NP problem. By the way proof for the general case nets you one million dollars since it hasnt been claimed either it dont exist or its worth more than 1 million dollars to keep i quiet. But optimizers that will find a somewhat optimal solution do exist its called a nesting software a generic one is [SVGnest](https://svgnest.com/), but the square problem is easier there exists more optimal nesters for that.

Comment: Sounds like you want some kind of layout software. Maybe even doesn't need to be that complex. Something free such as LibreOffice Draw could be used to resize images maintaining aspect ratio, and layout A4 pages. When finished, just export as PDF and print. If you have already have MS Office, probably also possible using Word or PowerPoint.

Comment: Thanks all! @BillyKerr and joojaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what software you currently have. If you are using Adobe photoshop, this is very easy.
You would create an action that resizes the image to 4.5. Then saves a copy and closes the image.
Then with nothing open you use the "batch process" to process the entire folder. It will run the action on all images until done.
If you also use the free Adobe Bridge software, you can batch process from there.

If you do not have Adobe... you want to search Google for "batch process images software"

Personally, I have fast stone resizer http://www.faststone.org/FSResizerDetail.htm

Here is one of the Google search results with 10 options ... https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/batch-image-processors-editors/